# Python Selenium Amazon Modal Box Element

Tags: python, selenium

I am sort of new to selenium and I have been trying to automate an amazon purchase using the "buy now" button and everything was going great but I can't seem to click the "Place order" button when the modal box shows up after clicking "buy now". I have tried getting the element by id, xpath, css-selector but still get element not found exception. I also tried switching windows and frames but no avail.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thank you.

Here is a sample product for reference:
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B08QZDGDNH/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A38TVE5WF50X65&psc=1

```
#btnPlaceOrder = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div/span/span/span/input')
#WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='turbo-checkout-pyo-button']"))).click()
#btnPlaceOrder = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="turbo-checkout-pyo-button"]')

#switch to small frame
#window_after = browser.window_handles[0]
#browser.switch_to_window(window_after)
#browser.switch_to_window("CDwindow-881C8A0F3B4DA3AB683945CC21C9EB07")
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit of the html of the page where the modal is?

Comment: Localy I am able to get the buy now button with buy_button = driver.find_element_by_id('buy-now-button') could you give more context? Which browser/driver are you using?

Comment: @EdoardoRosso,@Felipe I was able to solve it please see solution below. Basically there was an iframe container that I did not spot in the html code. Solution was to switch to the frame before clicking any button.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't notice there was an iframe in the html:

```
<iframe id="turbo-checkout-iframe" src="about:blank" scrolling="no" class="turbo-checkout-blank turbo-checkout-shown" style="height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

The following did the trick:

```
#switch to iframe container
browser.switch_to.frame("turbo-checkout-iframe")
#place order button     
btnPlaceOrder = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="turbo-checkout-pyo-button"]').click()
```