# How to click buttons on amazon with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I'm trying to click buttons on amazon with selenium (python) but it won't work. It says the elements don't exist. I tried to google it but only found outdated solutions. I've tried Xpaths,ID,full XPATH on pretty much all input fields with no success. I've used selenium before and it works flawlessly  but on amazon in particular it can't find the elements. For example the place order button (Je bestelling plaatsen in my language) can't be found nor clicked.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="turbo-checkout-pyo-button"]/span/input')

driver.find_element(By.ID, 'turbo-checkout-pyo-button')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div/span/span/span/input')
```

How do I know which elements are clickable and direct to the intended page? If there is a way to tell please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since this is a public web site - please share the page you are working on and explain what button are you trying to click?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I edited the question

Comment: I still see no relevant details: link ?

Comment: It's the place order button on amazon after clicking buy now on any product. It should give the prompt as shown on the image. I'm trying to click the marked button as seen above named place order button. Product as shown in example: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07NRG8KJK/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A36IUCB8PDIF5F&th=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the button was located in an iframe. Switching to the iframe and then pressing the button does the job. Found out through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283099/python-selenium-amazon-modal-box-element?rq=1) question

```
driver.switch_to.frame("turbo-checkout-iframe")
directButton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#turbo-checkout-pyo-button')
directButton.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a selenium master but you can use the `find_element_by_xpath` function that returns an element object that can be clicked so:

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div/span/span/span/input')
element.click()
```

Comment: I know, but the elements are not found when running the command (on amazon only). I have used selenium on other sites before and it worked flawlessly but amazon in particular doesn't work.